# How to find letter in all columns with Spring Data JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, repository, spring-data-jpa

Here is my Repository

```
public interface NoteRepository extends JpaRepository<Note,Long> {
    List<Note> findByContentContains(String content);
```

and my method in class NoteController which return me words with "e" in column Content

```
@GetMapping("/notesletter")
    public List<String> getLetters(){
        return noteRepository.findByContentContains("e")
                .stream()
                .map(note -> note.getContent())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Please, help me to find a method which will return every words with letter "e",for example, from all columns.
I am working with Postman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can you native queries

```
 @Query("select u from Note u where u.COL1 = ?1 and u.COL2 = ?1")
 List<Note> findByContentContains(String content)
```

or use jpa feature as given  below, Note findByLastnameOrFirstnameStartingWith is mentioned to understand easily, so replace your firstname,lastname as colu1name,col2name respectively.[Refer here for more jpa method conventions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html)`

```
public interface NoteRepository extends JpaRepository<Note,Long> {

     List<Note> findByLastnameOrFirstnameStartingWith(String param1,String param2)

     static List<Note> findByContentContains(String content){
      findByLastnameOrFirstnameStartingWith(content,content);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the or operation in the method name like below.
Or  findByLastnameOrFirstname

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html

Other approaches are possible too.

If you know the native query or JPQL equivalent that returns the results checking all the columns of the entity.

Use of

> **`@Query`** above the method in repository interface can take a JPQL or native query.
>
> **`@NamedQuery`** annotation is also available if you know the query. This annotation to be used over the Entity class, name attribute is used to specify the accessing method name which returns the data, this can be used in repository interface.